# Java calass "Data" forces close upon startup / when i click it from the menu on my phone

Tags: android

```
 package com.thenewboston.travis;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Data extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     Button start, startFor;
 EditText sendET;
     TextView gotAnswer;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.get);
         initialize();
                     }
     private void initialize() {
         //TODO Auto-Generated method stub
         start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSA);
         startFor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSA);
         sendET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSend);
         gotAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGot);
         start.setOnClickListener(this);
         startFor.setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (arg0.getId()){
         case R.id.bSA:
             String bread = sendET.getText().toString();
             Bundle basket = new Bundle();
             basket.putString("key", bread);
             Intent a = new Intent(Data.this, OpenedClass.class);
             a.putExtras(basket);
             startActivity(a);

             break;
         case R.id.bSAFR:

                 break;
             }

         }


        }`
```

Below is my logcat trace :

```
03-12 18:29:54.414: D/dalvikvm(331): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 734 objects / 54640 bytes in 68ms
    03-12 18:30:01.843: D/AndroidRuntime(331): Shutting down VM
    03-12 18:30:01.843: W/dalvikvm(331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.thenewboston.travis/com.thenewboston.travis.Data}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.thenewboston.travis.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:32)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:321)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have to supply us with a stack trace. In that stack trace lies the answer.

Comment: you have both start and startfor referencing same id

Comment: cool were do i fing the stack trace ive heard of it

Comment: 03-11 19:41:59.913: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 19:41:59.913: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-11 19:41:59.913: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-11 19:41:59.913: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-11 19:41:59.913: E/AndroidRuntime(317):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: This is not a full error trace and please post it in your question and not in comments.

Comment: I fixed the bSA too bSAFR still doesnt work ill send the stack trace when I find it and the Log Cat soon thanks heaps for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your manifest file :

```
<activity android:name="com.thenewboston.travis.Data>       
</activity>
```

Thanks.

Comment: But its set in between intent brackets eg. ...boston.travis.Data> and intent.category.default

Answer (score 0):

Look at these lines:
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.thenewboston.travis/com.thenewboston.travis.Data}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 03-12 18:30:01.853: E/AndroidRuntime(331)
There is your answer, You don't declare your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Sorry so sorry Your Right Demand how stupid I had the activity in the .Menu activity